# SSHFS freezes in bash but in tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, sshfs, tcsh

I run SSHFS on a cluster which I am not root on.
Therefore, I use SSHFS 2.4 (as it does not require installing fuse which I cannot as I'm not root, also I am able to run the executable out of box without `apt install`).
I am able to mount the following partition in `tcsh`:

```
echo "CENSORED" | ./sshfs/bin/sshfs -o password_stdin -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no CENSORED@CENSORED.DOMAIN.COM:/ /SOME/CENSORED/PATH
```

But in `bash` something strange happens.
There is a blank line in the terminal. It waits a minute and then:

```
Timeout waiting for prompt
```

It seems to be unrelated to wait for fingerprint approval as StrictHostKeyChecking is applied.
This is strange it happens in `bash` but not `tcsh` maybe it is `bash` related?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

EDIT:
it seems the bug occurs here:
https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/6a2d06e36fe73e592e02a16ff5025ec622eb015e/sshfs.c#L916

Does anyone know why bash behaves differently in this context? And how to detour this?

Comment: In the code you linked to I can see the tool waits for a prompt containing `assword`. When you just `ssh CENSORED@CENSORED.DOMAIN.COM`, what prompt do you get? Is there a difference between doing it in `tcsh` and `bash`?